# How can I recover an RTF file that comes up blank in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, rtf

How can I recover an RTF file that comes up blank in Word? I've tried copy-pasting its contents into a new document and opening it with Notepad. In Notepad, it shows up as a bunch of zeros and the formatting text for Word. I tried opening the file with a hex editor, too, but I'm not totally familiar with them and was unsure what to do next.

Comment: Is it a Word file (.DOC) as opposed to an RTF? Try opening it in a Word viewer. Try importing it to Google Docs or something.

Comment: Have you exhausted all other program options, like OpenOffice? Maybe give the file to a Mac user and see if he can do anything with it.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Wordpad? Not sure if it'll help, but worth a shot.

Comment: If it's showing up as zeroes in Notepad, without any content, it sounds like your SOL.

Comment: Awesome, I'll check all these out.  Hopefully something works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on a user's PC at work.

Try deleting their profile's `normal.dot` file.

All Office applications should be closed before you delete the file. Sometimes these files are hidden; when you search for `normal.dot` you need to select *Advanced Options* and tick the box to *Search hidden files and folders*.

When you reopen Word, the `normal.dot` file will be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

try opening and saving the corrupted file in wordpad.

In linux,once wine installed, using the command

```
  wine wordpad
```

i have managed to open a corrupted file properly and retrieve it this way.

Comment: Cool. Wordpad opened my rtf, failed by both libre office and word